# Power Query Editor: Why are null Values Matching on an Inner Join?

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, power-query

I am using Power Query Editor in Excel for Microsoft 365.

Table **A** has a column **ID** that holds a unique identifier. This identifier is usually numeric, but it sometimes contains text. Given this, I've set this column's data type to **Text**.

Table **B** also has a column **ID** with the same properties as described above.

I am performing an inner join (merge) on these two tables with **ID** as the join column:

```
= Table.NestedJoin(A, {"ID"}, B, {"ID"}, "B", JoinKind.Inner)
```

This inner join is matching nulls, which I did not think was supposed to happen.

[image]

As a workaround, I've added an Applied Step to filter out null values in these columns. But, I'd like to get to the root of the problem.

How may I prevent null values from matching? Or am I incorrect in my understanding that two nulls should never match each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Power Query language specification, [the equality operator is defined on null values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-values#null).

[image]

Please also see the discussion:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119042/power-query-merging-on-null-values

In summary, it looks like you should remove or replace nulls from your tables before joining if you don't want them to be considered equal.